# Calculate Field tool in ModelBuilder only returns first value of string

Tags: modelbuilder, field-calculator, arcgis-pro

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.6.1.

In ModelBuilder, I am using a Calculate Field tool to determine a compliance status based on a color value derived from a Bentley DGN file. Here is the expression used:

```
Compliant(!Color!)
```

and here is the Code Block:

```py
def Compliant(Color):
    if Color == 2:
        x = "Compliant"
    else:
        x = "Non Compliant"
    return x
```

The code block correctly determines the status, however instead of writing "Compliant" or "Non Compliant" into the table, only a "C" or an "N" is captured.

This also works perfectly outside of the ModelBuilder, but behaves in the way described within ModelBuilder.

**Edit - Add Field Parameters**

As requested by @Hornbydd, here is an image displaying the Add Field tool parameters within ModelBuilder:

[image: Add Field parameters]

**Edit - Screenshot of Attribute Table**

As requested by @Hornbydd, here is an image displaying Attribute Table after executing the Model:

[image: Attribute table after Model execution]

Comment: What is the length of your output field?

Comment: @Taras, right before the Calculate Field tool I used an Add Field tool, Text, with a Length of 20. Is this what you mean by output field, or is there somewhere else I should look?

Comment: Are you apply some sort of Domain on the field? Edit your question by showing us an image of how the AddField tool parameters are set up.

Comment: @Hornbydd - edited the question to include the image of the Add Field too.

Comment: So your field calculate code looks OK to me, your AddField tool looks OK, could you add an additional screenshot of what your attribute table looks like after you have run the field calculate tool. Out of interest try removing the layer from the map then manually add it back (don't paste it back in, add it) what does the table look like then? Even try adding it into a blank project? My gut feeling is that you have sort sort of display glitch/legacy on your layer?

Comment: @Hornbydd - I've added the attribute table. I've since also created a new project and added the feature class to the map, but the display remains consistent, "C" and "N" only. What I am going to do next is recreate the model completely in a new project to check whether the error is still replicated.